# Excel: IF CellA = RangeX then Count adjacent in RangeY if equal to CellB

Tags: excel-formula

How do I write this formula within MS Excel?

IF CellA = RangeX then Count adjacent in RangeY if equal to CellB

[image]

Comment: Well, I would post the screenshot if I did not need rep to do so..... nvm now, I think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is in `$` sign that fixates position, and this is formula based on guess:

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$D4,$B:$B,E$3)
```

Comment: JEEZ, I can not believe I spent so much time on this. THANK YOU!

Comment: @Condar87 a good way to earn reputation and therefore the ability to upload pics, is to accept answers that address correctly your question :)